# Проблема с параллельным обрабатыванием двух скриптов бота Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь реализовать функции ежедневной рассылки, при этом что бы бот мог отвечать на получаемые запросы от пользователя.

```
import telebot
import schedule
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
#from PIL import Image
a = 0
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m, res=False):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'здарова')

# ответ бота 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ладно' )#+ message.text

c = "напоминание"

# Отработка отправки ежедневной рассылки
def job():
    print("исполнение")
    bot.send_message("id", c)
schedule.every(6).seconds.do(job)

while a<5:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)


while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except: 
      print('bolt')
```

в результате бесконечно отрабатывается первый скрипт который он встречает, и соответственно последующие функции бота не работают.
Просьба к знатокам, подсказать лучшее решение для данной проблемы.

Comment: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parallel-execution.html#parallel-execution

Comment: Ничего не имею против ``telebot``, но я бы посмотрел в сторону *асинхроной* ``aiogram`` - более оптимальный вариант для таких штук, да и для тг-ботов в целом